# Python uses huge amount of RAM to import file

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have an eigenvalue solver code which does the following:

- Imports a function from a Python file generated by another program which holds an algebraic matrix in the form of a mpmath matrix or numpy array depending on the problem.
- In the main script the matrix is evaluated for whatever values the variables will take, or a particular value in the matrix is optimised via a scipy routine.

The code works fine and I have been impressed with the speed of it thus far. I have hit a snag when I increase the matrix size, which causes the exernal file to grow quite substantially. The file size I am importing is 1.5GB. The imported file has the form (example for a much smaller 4x4 mp.matrix):

```
from __future__ import division
import mpmath as mp

def myfuncSS(A,B,C,D):
    SS = mp.matrix([1/B**3/(A+B)**6*A**3+6/B**2/(A+B)**6*A**2+15/B/(A+B)**6*A+84/(A+B)**6+15*B/(A+B)**6/A+6*B**2/(A+B)**6/A**2+B**3/(A+B)**6/A**3,0,0,0],[-1/2/B**3/(A+B)**6*A**3-7/2/B**2/(A+B)**6*A**2-19/2/B/(A+B)**6*A-53/(A+B)**6-19/2*B/(A+B)**6/A-7/2*B**2/(A+B)**6/A**2-1/2*B**3/(A+B)**6/A**3,2/B**3/(A+B)**6*A**3+14/B**2/(A+B)**6*A**2+38/B/(A+B)**6*A+212/(A+B)**6+38*B/(A+B)**6/A+14*B**2/(A+B)**6/A**2+2*B**3/(A+B)**6/A**3,0,0],[-2/B**3/(A+B)**7*A**4-25/2/B**2/(A+B)**7*A**3-65/2/B/(A+B)**7*A**2+37/2/(A+B)**7*A-253*B/(A+B)**7-35/2*B**2/(A+B)**7/A-9/2*B**3/(A+B)**7/A**2-1/2*B**4/(A+B)**7/A**3,1/B**3/(A+B)**7*A**4+13/2/B**2/(A+B)**7*A**3+33/2/B/(A+B)**7*A**2-19/(A+B)**7*A+118*B/(A+B)**7+9/2*B**2/(A+B)**7/A+1/2*B**3/(A+B)**7/A**2,7/B**3/(A+B)**8*A**5+50/B**2/(A+B)**8*A**4+154/B/(A+B)**8*A**3+331/(A+B)**8*A**2-147*B/(A+B)**8*A+848*B**2/(A+B)**8+80*B**3/(A+B)**8/A+19*B**4/(A+B)**8/A**2+2*B**5/(A+B)**8/A**3,0],[-1/2/B**3/(A+B)**7*A**4-9/2/B**2/(A+B)**7*A**3-35/2/B/(A+B)**7*A**2-253/(A+B)**7*A+37/2*B/(A+B)**7-65/2*B**2/(A+B)**7/A-25/2*B**3/(A+B)**7/A**2-2*B**4/(A+B)**7/A**3,1/2/B**2/(A+B)**7*A**3+9/2/B/(A+B)**7*A**2+118/(A+B)**7*A-19*B/(A+B)**7+33/2*B**2/(A+B)**7/A+13/2*B**3/(A+B)**7/A**2+B**4/(A+B)**7/A**3,1/B**3/(A+B)**8*A**5+17/2/B**2/(A+B)**8*A**4+31/B/(A+B)**8*A**3-305/2/(A+B)**8*A**2+1568*B/(A+B)**8*A-305/2*B**2/(A+B)**8+31*B**3/(A+B)**8/A+17/2*B**4/(A+B)**8/A**2+B**5/(A+B)**8/A**3,2/B**3/(A+B)**8*A**5+19/B**2/(A+B)**8*A**4+80/B/(A+B)**8*A**3+848/(A+B)**8*A**2-147*B/(A+B)**8*A+331*B**2/(A+B)**8+154*B**3/(A+B)**8/A+50*B**4/(A+B)**8/A**2+7*B**5/(A+B)**8/A**3]])
    return SS
```

In the main script this function is called via:

```
from 'filename' import myfuncSS
```

1.5GB is a fair size for a file; however the memory required to import this is outlandish compared to the size of file. It tries to use up all 32GB of memory along with all virtual memory that my system has before I receive the `killed 9` external error showing a SIGKILL error (and rightly so). Why does Python use such a huge amount of RAM to import this file to memory? What would be a better option for reading in such a function?

Comment: "The file size I am importing is 1.5GB" - Is this a python file? Why is it so big? What does it contain?

Comment: It contains a matrix where each element is either 0, or an algebraic form which is then evaluated by the function.

Comment: Do you have some rule regarding the algebraic forms? How did you generate this file? If you have some code which generated this file, you should modify it to define a function similar to above without generating the file

Comment: Thank you for your help. The file is generated by a Maple script which has to do a lot of maths to get the matrix into the correct format. This matrix is general and only needs to be generated once; but can be used to solve a huge variety of problems by assigning values to the variables. Rather than make the matrix every time a problem needs to be solved, it has already been created and just needs to be evaluated.

Comment: "Rather than make the matrix every time a problem needs to be solved" - Is the generation of the matrix very complex? Have you tried what I stated? The parsing of a file so big requires a large amount of data that needs to be stored somewhere. If it's absolutely necessary, try converting this to [`pyc`](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-create-a-pyc-file.htm) file.

Comment: I believed that is what was killing it. By my understanding Python will automatically compile imported modules to form .pyc files. If I compile the external file manually using $python -m 'filename.py' . I receive the same killed:9 error. 

I guess the matrix formation is complicated, which i why I use Maple to symbolically simplify as much as possible.

Comment: You can try converting that part of code to C, using cython. I do not have much details, but it would definitely save some memory